# OpenGL ModelView Confusion

Tags: opengl, graphics

I am using opengl 2.0  with the fixed function pipeline. It seems that in opengl 2.0
they push the vertices through the model-view stack which is basically (view matrix * model matrix), in which the model matrix doesn't provide any transformation really it brings an object say a cube to be centered at (0,0,0) if the model view matrix has a identity matrix loaded.Also the camera it self would be located at (0,0,0) looking down the negative z axis.

So if I use a translate call with the cube I am I really moving the cube in Eye space ?

From what I learned the generalized viewing pipeline is

Vertices -> Modelling Matrix -> World Space, Objects in World Space -> Viewing Matrix -> Eye Space, Eye Space Objects -> Projection Matrix -> Clipping Space , Then normalization ect

So If I switch to the 
model view matrix stack()
loadidentity ()
gltranslate ( up 5 units in the negative z direction)
gldrawcube()

it would move the cube from center of the eye space according to the translation ?

I think my confusion is that I don't know what is loaded into the model view matrix stack when the program starts, I assume it is an identity matrix that brings everything to the centre of the eye space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a newly created OpenGL context all matrices are identity, i.e. vectors go through untransformed. In fixed function OpenGL vertex transformation skips the "world" step, collapsing object→world and world→eye into a single transformation. This is no big deal however. Lighting calculations are easiest in eye space anyway. And since fixed function OpenGL doesn't know shaders (except as extension), there's no need to do things in world space.

*glTranslate, glRotate, glScale* don't transform objects. They manipulate the matrix on top of the stack active for manipulation. So ultimately they contribute to the transformation, but not on the object, but the vertex (position) level.

> it would move the cube from center of the eye space according to the translation?

Indeed, but what's "moved" (actually transformed) are the cube's vertices; and it may be not just a translation.

**EDIT due to comment**

The key thing to understand is transformation composition. First and foremost a transformation is a mapping

```
T: R^4 -> R^4, v' = v |-> T(v)
```

There's a subset of transformation, namely the linear transformations which can be represented by matrix multiplication:

```
v' = T * v
```

one can concatenate transformations, i.e. `v = v |-> T'○T (v)` again for the subset of linear transformations, written in matrix form you can expand this to

```
v' = T * v
v'' = T' * v'

=>

v'' = T' * T * v
```

Now let `V` denote the viewing transform and `W` the world transform. So the total transform is

```
M = V * W
```

The order of matrix multiplication matters (i.e. matrix multiplication is not commutative):

```
∃ M, N ∊ {Matrices}: M * N ≠ N * M
```

The view transform `V` is the transform of the whole world so that it is moved in a way, that the camera in the world ends up being at the origin, viewing down the negative Z axis. So let `V'` be the transform that moves "the camera" from the origin at it's place in the world, the inverse of that movement moves the world in a way that the camera comes to rest at the origin. So

```
V = inv(V')
```

Last but not least given some matrices A, B, C for which holds

```
A = B * C
```

then

```
inv(A) = inv(C) * inv(B)
```

i.e. the order of operations reversed. So if you "position" your "camera" using inverse OpenGL matrix operations, the order of the operations must be reversed. And since the overall order of operation matters the viewing transformations must happen before the model transformations.

Comment: I just find modelview really confusing in red book it says "Thus, a modeling transformation that rotates an object counterclockwise is equivalent to a viewing transformation that rotates the camera clockwise, for example. Finally, keep in mind that the viewing transformation commands must be called before any modeling transformations are performed, so that the modeling transformations take effect on the objects first. "

Why must they be performed first ? in my head I am thinking (View Mat * (Model Mat * Vertex))

and do they mean like for example 
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW) 
loadIdentity()

Comment: glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW) 
loadIdentity()
//move "Camera here "

glpushmatrix()
gltranslate()
gldrawcube()
glpopmatrix()

Is there a good tutorial that explains this modelview matrix ? its a diffcult concept to me

Comment: Okay all that made sense except I was wondering what does opengl modelview then have by default on the stack ? the view matrix (moves camera to origin so that the point of view is the camera's) * identity (modeling matrix) ? So it seems in theory that I have to multiply by the invviewing matrix to get the world space, at the application level then once I do that I move the camera around using translations and rotations then apply the viewing matrix that centres the camera again so I am in eye space?

Comment: You know what my confusion was ? Model view is just the name of the matrix stack, So that stack actually starts with an identity matrix, in which since MV = V * M, I must apply viewing transformation first in which it is optional to apply a modeling transformation. If I did want to apply a modeling transformation then I would have to make sure I do my viewing first then my modeling matrix transformation, so that the verticies are multiplied by the modeling then the viewing, otherwise the verticies are just multiplied by the viewing in the other case.

Comment: So initally MV = I * I = I so the vertices would just make a pass through to eye space making sure everything ends up at the origin, so technically viewing and modeling is the same depends on how you think about it

Comment: @GeorgeHost: The stack comes into play if you use glPushMatrix, glPopMatrix. If you don't use those, there is no stack. OpenGL has 4 matrices: projection, modelview, texture and color. For each of those matrices a stack is maintained, of which ONLY the uppermost element is used. The whole stack is only there, to make implementing transformation hierachies easier. glRotate, glTranslate, glScale don't "stack". Also the modelview matrix is only one single matrix, not two distinct ones.

Comment: Thanks yeah I was confused about how a single stack for two transformations worked that single stack accomplishes two passes through model then view but in a single matrix, and yeah you pin pointed there is only a stack if you use glpush or glpop thank you!!!!